# Redirecting using NextJS middleware except specific pages

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm aware there are a number of posts regarding this topic, nothing specifically for this issue though.

I'm using T3 stack and whilst my app is being developed I want all client requests to be directed to a particular route, in this case `/signup`.

I've written this, and this works:

```
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {   
    const url = request.nextUrl.clone()
    if (!url.pathname.startsWith('/signup') && // exlude the signup page to avoid redirect loop
        !url.pathname.startsWith('/_next') && // exclude Next.js internals
        !url.pathname.startsWith('/_axiom') && // exclude Axiom
        !url.pathname.startsWith('/_api') && // exclude all API routes
        !url.pathname.includes('.')) // exclude public files
    {
        url.pathname = '/signup'
        return NextResponse.redirect(url)   
    } 
}
```

This is rather convoluted though and I'd rather use matcher if I can do do it instead.

I've tried this:

```
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) { 
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/signup", request.url));
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/((?!signup|_axiom|_api|_next/static|_next/image).*)",
  ],
};
```

This doesn't seem to pick up the matcher the way I expect it to but both the middleware and config is being read. If I remove the config, the redirect is attempted but fails with too many attempts.

Ideally I'd like to use something similar to the second option, especially if the conditionals get more complicated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and test a more concise way to achieve your goal, while still keeping the logic within the [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware): use a Regular Expression (regex) to test the pathname of the request.

```js
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
    const excludedPaths = /^(\/signup|\/_next|\/_axiom|\/_api|.*\..*)/;
    if (!excludedPaths.test(url.pathname)) {
        url.pathname = '/signup';
        return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }
}
```

This uses a regular expression `excludedPaths`, created to match the paths that should be excluded from redirection.
The `test()` method is used to check if `url.pathname` matches any of the excluded paths.
If `url.pathname` does not match any of the excluded paths, it is redirected to `/signup`.

This approach avoids the lengthy series of conditionals and should provide a more compact solution.

---

That being said, considering "[How to use matcher in Next.js middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73386410/6309)", for Next.js version 12.2, the `middleware.ts` file should be placed in the project root, while for version 13.1.6, it should be placed in the `src` directory.
If you are using Next.js version 13.1.6 or a similar version, moving the `middleware.ts` file to the `src` directory as suggested might resolve the issue.

And you may need to adjust the regular expression in the [`matcher`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher) property to make sure it correctly matches the routes you want to handle.

```js
// File path: <project-root>/src/middleware.ts

import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/signup", request.url));
}

export const config = {
    matcher: new RegExp("/((?!signup|_axiom|_api|_next/static|_next/image).*)"),
};
```

That would place the `middleware.ts` file in the `src` directory for Next.js version 13.1.6, and updates the `matcher` property to use a `RegExp` object instead of a string.

Comment: Great thanks, I had to implement an auth middleware and after revisiting the matcher, it's now behaving as expected.

Comment: @MM1010 Great, well done!